# Trying to merge into a dataframe but it keeps creating new columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to open files and derive 2 columns(1 row for each) from multiple spreadsheets and then merging them to a base spreadsheet.So, the base dataframe (derived from a spreadsheet, from which I only needed 3 columns)  is like this :

```
Model |  Roadmap | Family
a       08/12/17  ROW
b       08/14/17  MACRO 
c       08/15/17  CONN 
d       08/27/17  MACRO
```

The dataframes from the multiple spreadsheets(the model names are the spreadsheet names and they have multiple dates for each gate which i am deriving in multiple dataframes) and have this format :

```
    df1 (part1 -  the dataframe derived from the spreadsheet with model a for gate 0 ):
    Model   |  Gate 0 
    a         02/01/18  

df1 (Dataframe derived from the spreadsheet with model a for gate1):
        Model   |  Gate 1
        a         03/01/18   


   df2 (part1):
    Model  |  Gate 0 
    b       04/23/18   

df2 (part1):
        Model  |  Gate 1 
        b       05/23/18
```

The output it produces is :

```
Model |  Roadmap | Family | Gate 0_x  | Gate 1_x   | gate 0_y | Gate 1_y
a       08/12/17  ROW      02/01/18   03/01/18  
b       08/14/17  MACRO                              04/23/18  05/23/18     
c       08/15/17  CONN
d       08/27/17  MACRO
```

the output i want :

```
  Model |  Roadmap | Family | Gate 0   | Gate 1   
   a       08/12/17  ROW     02/01/18   03/01/18
   b       08/14/17  MACRO    04/23/18  05/23/18 
   ..
```

The following is the code i am using:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import re
import ntpath




extension = 'xlsx'
d='Final.xlsx'
c = 'Roadmap.xlsx'
dflist = []
z=[]
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

for b in result:
    if b==c:
        base_file = pd.read_excel(b, sheet_name='Antennas', header=7)
        ind1 = base_file.set_index('Model')
        ind1 = base_file[['Model', 'Roadmap', 'Family']]
        #print(ind1)
        ind1.to_excel('Final.xlsx')
        file3 = pd.read_excel('Final.xlsx')
        file3= file3.replace(r'[,\"\']','', regex=True).replace(r'\s*([^\s]+)\s*', r'\1', regex=True)



for a in result:

        if a == c:
            base_file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name='Antennas', header=7)
            ind1 = base_file.set_index('Model')
            ind1 = base_file[['Model', 'Roadmap', 'Family']]
            ind1.to_excel('Final.xlsx')
        elif a != d:
            gates = ['Gate 0 Complete','Gate 1 Complete'] 
            file1 = pd.read_excel('Final.xlsx')
            file1= file1.replace(r'[,\"\']','', regex=True).replace(r'\s*([^\s]+)\s*', r'\1', regex=True)     
            #print(file1)
            file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name='Timeline')
            #print(file)
            models = pd.DataFrame([['','']], columns=['Model', gates])
            for g in gates:      
                z = file.loc[file['Task'] == g, 'Complete'].iloc[0]
                v=ntpath.basename(a)
                v = v[5:-5]
                models = pd.DataFrame([[v,z]], columns =['Model',g])
                file1 = pd.merge(file1, models, how='left', on='Model')
            file3 = pd.merge(file3, file1, how='left' ,['Model','Roadmap','Family'])
            file3.to_excel('new.xlsx')
```

file3 is the file i have opened as the dataframe for the base file before the for loop. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: are the names of the columns exactly the same?

Comment: You may want to add some sample data of your actual files and remove parts of the code that are not necessary (like the regex it looks like) to help others see the error faster. @MaartenFabré's comment happens more than you think - try trimming up leading/trailing spaces

Comment: @MaartenFabré they are the same however, when i am merging the first file is fine but when the second file(dataframe) comes in it adds the roadmap and family column again and then it adds the two gates with _y prefix and the first 2 with _x prefix. I fixed the roadmap and family column being joined again by merging on those columns as well. Look at the edit.

Comment: @MattR better? Is this an issue because the merge doesnt specify the join on those gate columns as well?

Comment: So, file3 and file1 have the same structure? Except file1 has the new gate1 and gate 0 columns?

Comment: @Rahul Yes!!!!!

Comment: Pandas like Python in general is case sensitive: `Gate1 != gate1`.

Comment: @Parfait yes sir. Exactly identical column names. That is why even the script names it gate 0 _X and gate 0 _y to avoid confusion. 

Can you tell me if there is a way to check if multiple column names exist in a dataframe?

Comment: The problem could be caused by mismatched column names. In all the dataframes, use uppercase G for Gatex and delete leading/trailing spaces. eg. ' gatex ' should become 'Gatex'.

Comment: @WR dont believe that is the issue. Did that. You pointed it out in your answer.. it is due to merging with the same dataset.

Comment: In your updated OP, what is `df1 (part 1)` versus `df2 (part1)`? what is different about those 2 dataframes?

Comment: @WR made the edit.

Comment: For some reason I am convinced your problem is caused **ONLY** by column names that are *not* the same. I think @MaartenFabré was suggesting the same above.

Comment: @WR I wish that would be the case. I can tell you its not because when it creates those 2 columns for 1 gate it prefixes the gate names by x and y just to distinguish them. if they would be different this wouldnt be done right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you are merging twice but really need to merge *base* with individual dfs and then append all together with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

Below recreates your posted examples above which assumes same structure as Excel files  and demonstrates the merge and append steps. You will notice `drop_duplicates` is used due to the *left join* merges that render same row values. Keep or remove this method on actual data.

**Data**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''
Model  Roadmap  Family
a      some_date  some
b      some_date  some 
c      some_date  some 
d      some_date  some
'''
base_df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

txt = '''
Model  "Gate 0" "Gate 1"
    a   some_date  some 
'''
df1 = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

txt = '''
Model  "Gate 0" "Gate 1"
    b   some_date  some 
'''
df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")
```

**Merge and Append** *(using list comprehension)*

```
finaldf = pd.concat([pd.merge(base_df, df, how='left', on='Model') 
                    for df in [df1, df2]], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates()

print(finaldf)
#   Model    Roadmap Family     Gate 0 Gate 1
# 0     a  some_date   some  some_date   some
# 1     b  some_date   some        NaN    NaN
# 2     c  some_date   some        NaN    NaN
# 3     d  some_date   some        NaN    NaN
# 4     a  some_date   some        NaN    NaN
# 5     b  some_date   some  some_date   some
```

To integrate in your current process, consider appending individual *models* into a list to be concatenated and merged at the end. Build *base_df* as your posted example above.

```
...
dfList = []

for g in gates:      
     z = file.loc[file['Task'] == g, 'Complete'].iloc[0]
     v = ntpath.basename(a)
     v = v[5:-5]
     mod = pd.DataFrame([[v,z]], columns =['Model',g])
     models = pd.merge(models, mod, how='left', on='Model')
dfList.append(models)

finaldf = pd.merge(base_df, pd.concat(dfList), how='left', on='Model')
finaldf.to_excel('Final_Dataset.xlsx')
```

Comment: but you are considering this if both df1 and df2 exist at the same time right? I am creating the df1 first then i merge it with the base_df then df2 is created and merged with the base_df. I dont think this can be done using your code, can it?

Comment: Do this. Create all dfs in one process (no merge/append) and then run this process afterwards where you read all dfs into a list and run the list comprehension approach. You can even reverse where you concatenate the list of dfs, and then merge once: `pd.merge(base_df, pd.concat([dfList]), how='left', on='Model')`. Even more no output to Excel is even needed!

Comment: Are you saying create dataframes and insert them in a list? Gotcha... i want to capture the final dataset into excel.

Comment: Converting dataframes into list is hard (never done it) also after converting i have to append them. When i say `df.values.tolist()`, it just gives me records and not the columns. Any workaround?

Comment: Oh no! That is not what I meant. Not values within dataframe but list of dataframes themselves. See extended answer to integrate in current setup.

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that dont know the rules of operating here that well.

Comment: Could you tell me what you are doing here with the if statement. This is producing excessive number of rows, duplicates and giving 2 gate columns each.

Comment: You were very close with the previous edit. Just need to find a way to merge it to the base_df with the model and not duplicate it.

Comment: I am not trying to copy and paste (trying not to) . I have been beating my head for about a day on this now.  As i told you i am new here, i tried to explain what i was doing. Yes, i create a dataframe for each gate and then combine them with the base df. Can you tell me a way to merge the individual dfs together for each gate, which will be much easier to combine to the base df. You have been of great help tho and i will be over the top if we can solve this.

Comment: i can explain something that you are not able to understand in my code.

Comment: Hey, so the lists that we created, what do you think if i create a function to recreate the list such that the first item is model followed by the gate numbers.  is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, that is because the spreadsheet from which we are deriving the dataframe has a sheet named Timeline. If you just create those dataframes and execute the code, it will run (Obviously, you will have to remove the lines where i am extracting data from the spreadsheet).

Comment: BTW i have posted the answer in the question. Just change your answer and i will mark it as right. You helped a lot :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got how to do it. Let me know if you find any issues.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import re
import ntpath

extension = 'xlsx'
d='Final.xlsx'
c = 'Roadmap.xlsx'
dflist = []
z=[]
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

for a in result:

    if a == c:
        base_file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name='Antennas', header=7)
        ind1 = base_file.set_index('Model')
        ind1 = base_file[['Model', 'Roadmap', 'Family']]
        #print(ind1)
        ind1.to_excel('Final.xlsx')
    elif a != d:
        v=ntpath.basename(a)
        v = v[5:-5]
        gates = ['Gate 0 Complete','Gate 1 Complete', 'Gate 2 Complete'] 
        file1 = pd.read_excel('Final.xlsx')
        file1= file1.replace(r'[,\"\']','', regex=True).replace(r'\s*([^\s]+)\s*', r'\1', regex=True)     
        #print(file1)
        file = pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name='Timeline')
        #print(file)
        models = pd.DataFrame([[v]], columns=['Model'])
        #print(models)
        for g in gates:      
            z = file.loc[file['Task'] == g, 'Complete'].iloc[0]
            #print(z)
            #v = re.findall(r'Scrum(\w+)', a)
            #print(v)
            #df1=pd.DataFrame([[v,z]], columns = ['Model',g])
            mod = pd.DataFrame([[v,z]], columns =['Model',g])
            models=pd.merge(models, mod, how='left', on='Model')
            #print(models)
        dflist.append(models)
        #print(dflist)
file1 = pd.merge(file1,pd.concat(dflist), how='left',on='Model')
file1.to_excel('new.xlsx')
```

Comment: @Parfait Let me know if you find any issues. Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: Most of the time, StackOverflow answers will not answer **exactly** the original poster's issue. Usually answers help in the underlying concept that needs to be tailored to fit the OP's needs. This is part of the learning process. Only one line really differs from above, the loop's inner `merge` with `dflist` indent. I did update accordingly.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, i understand. Yea i should have thought of the merge sooner. But yea glad i got it :D

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the following about your raw data:

1. STEP 0 - Part 1. You load `df_base`
2. STEP 0 - Part 2. You load `df1`, `df2`, etc. - one `df` for each sheet

Then my approach would be to perform the following steps (in order):

1. Vertically concatenate `df` for all sheets together into single DataFrame named `df_sheets`
2. merge `df_base` with `df_sheets` to get the desired output

Based on this,my approach would be:

```
import pandas as pd

# STEP 0.
cv = ['a','b','c','d']
nr = 4

# STEP 0 - Part 1. Load Base DF
cv = cv[:nr]
df_base = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[cv,['some_date']*nr,['some']*nr]),
                  columns=['Model','Roadmap','Family'])

# STEP 0 - Part 2. Load Sheets DataFrames
df_sheets = []
for alph in cv:
    df_sheet = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[[alph]*nr,['some_date_'+alph]*nr,['some_'+alph]*nr]),
                            columns=['Model','Gate0','Gate1'])
    df_sheets.append(df_sheet)
print('Base DF:\n{}' .format(df_base))


# STEP 1. Vertically conctenate all sheets DataFrames together
df_sheets = pd.concat(df_sheets, axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
print('\nDataFrames for all sheets (vertically concatenated into single DataFrame):\n{}'
    .format(df_sheets))


# STEP 2. base INNER JOIN sheets USING ('Model')
ndf = df_base.merge(df_sheets, on='Model', how='inner')
print('\nOutput DataFrame:\n{}' .format(ndf))
```

Output is:

```
Base DF:
  Model    Roadmap Family
0     a  some_date   some
1     b  some_date   some
2     c  some_date   some
3     d  some_date   some

DataFrames for all sheets (vertically concatenated into single DataFrame):
   Model        Gate0   Gate1
0      a  some_date_a  some_a
1      a  some_date_a  some_a
2      a  some_date_a  some_a
3      a  some_date_a  some_a
4      b  some_date_b  some_b
5      b  some_date_b  some_b
6      b  some_date_b  some_b
7      b  some_date_b  some_b
8      c  some_date_c  some_c
9      c  some_date_c  some_c
10     c  some_date_c  some_c
11     c  some_date_c  some_c
12     d  some_date_d  some_d
13     d  some_date_d  some_d
14     d  some_date_d  some_d
15     d  some_date_d  some_d

Output DataFrame:
   Model    Roadmap Family        Gate0   Gate1
0      a  some_date   some  some_date_a  some_a
1      a  some_date   some  some_date_a  some_a
2      a  some_date   some  some_date_a  some_a
3      a  some_date   some  some_date_a  some_a
4      b  some_date   some  some_date_b  some_b
5      b  some_date   some  some_date_b  some_b
6      b  some_date   some  some_date_b  some_b
7      b  some_date   some  some_date_b  some_b
8      c  some_date   some  some_date_c  some_c
9      c  some_date   some  some_date_c  some_c
10     c  some_date   some  some_date_c  some_c
11     c  some_date   some  some_date_c  some_c
12     d  some_date   some  some_date_d  some_d
13     d  some_date   some  some_date_d  some_d
14     d  some_date   some  some_date_d  some_d
15     d  some_date   some  some_date_d  some_d
```

Is this what you are after?

Comment: Yes, pretty much let me try to implement this and ill get back to you. Thanks! A thing to note is that, the gates are in a list as well.

Comment: So there could be a list of gates like: `gate_list = [Gate0, Gate1, Gate2, Gate3,...]`?

Comment: Yes, i am going through each gate in the list and then creating the dataframe. Which is then appended to the base dataset, so the `file1 = pd.merge(file1, models, how='left', on='Model')` that you see in my code is actually merging the gates and their records to base dataset. So, this is 1 spreadsheet, now another spreadsheet comes in and another similar dataframe is created the issues is to merge them. These do not exist in the same timeframe. One is created after the other.